# How to get interface type of class properties for a factory method

Tags: typescript

I have a factory method in some of my code where I want to pass in not only a Class type to instantiate, but a set of default values for the properties in the class.  I would like to get the typing such that the compiler will tell me if I try to pass in properties that do not exist in the class type being instantiated.  I can't figure out how to do this though.

Here is a simple example showing what I would like to do.

When I try it, I get a compiler error of: "An interface may only extend a class or another interface." for the interface `ClassProps` because it can't extend from `T`.

```
class Base {
   myId: number;
}

class Klass1 extends Base {
   myString: string;
   myNumber: number;
}

interface IBaseCtr<T> {
   new (): T;
}

// Get an interface that is the properties of the class passed
interface ClassProps<T extends Base> extends T {}

// This method compiles, but doesn't check the prop names
//function factory<T extends Base>(ctrFunc: IBaseCtr<T>,
//                                 initialData?: Object): T

function factory<T extends Base>(ctrFunc: IBaseCtr<T>,
                                 initialData?: ClassProps<T>): T
{
   let new_obj = new ctrFunc();
   Object.assign(new_obj, initialData);
   return new_obj;
}


let v1 = factory(Klass1, {myId: 10, myString: 'foo'});

let v2 = factory(Klass1, {badVar: 10});
```

Any ideas how to get `initialData` typed so it will flag `badVar` as not being allowed in this second call?

Comment: Interesting. In the past I've constructed an interface to represent the class data and had the class extend that, but I'm guessing that won't be good enough here?

Comment: @Paarth I have done that in other places as well.  For this case though I can't use that method due to how other developers are putting together the classes and a couple of other related constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a lovely question.

Here's my approach. Remove that interface entirely.

```
function factory<T extends V, V extends Base>(ctrFunc: IBaseCtr<T>,
                                 initialData?: V): T
{
   let new_obj = new ctrFunc();
   Object.assign(new_obj, initialData);
   return new_obj;
}
```

This sets up a hierarchy, Base is a subset of properties in V, which is itself a subset of properties in T (your final type). v1 is assigned without error. v2's assignment statement causes an error at compile time.

You can actually go ahead and remove the `extends Base` portion to make this function applicable in more places. It will still typecheck the same way.

For giggles, a completely independent factory function signature that type checks correctly:

```
function factory<T extends V, V>(ctrFunc: new () => T,
                                 initialData?: V): T
```

Comment: That solution is awesome.  It does exactly what I want but I never thought of flipping the order of extends like like so the initial data is actually the "parent" of sorts.  Works great.  I am going to use your second form.  Thanks.

Comment: After looking closer, I will still use the second but it does have an issue that it doesn't ensure that T is a type that extends Base.  (note: The first option above doesn't actually work because it only ever has initialData setup with the properties from Base)

Comment: If you want to enforce that anything passed into this function has to extend from Base that's fine, the first one *should* work. Can you explain what's messing up?

Comment: The first one only allows initialData to contain properties that exist in Base.  Whereas what I want is for it to only allow properties that exist in T which must be extended from Base.  As a test, the "let v1 =.." line in the above code doesn't work with option 1.

Comment: I take that back.  Your solution does work.  I must have missed something when putting into my real code base.  I will try again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did things a bit differently than you did, but first the code:

```
interface BaseProperties {
    myId: number;
}

class Base<T extends BaseProperties> {
    protected myId: number;

    init(props: T): void {
        this.myId = props.myId;
    }
}

interface Klass1Properties extends BaseProperties {
    myString: string;
    myNumber: number
}

class Klass1 extends Base<Klass1Properties> {
    private myString: string;
    private myNumber: number;

    init(props: Klass1Properties): void {
        super.init(props);

        this.myString = props.myString;
        this.myNumber = props.myNumber;
    }
}

interface IBaseCtr<T> {
    new (): T;
}

function factory<P extends BaseProperties, T extends Base<P>>(ctrFunc: IBaseCtr<T>, initialData?: P): T {
    let new_obj = new ctrFunc();
    new_obj.init(initialData);
    return new_obj;
}


let v1 = factory(Klass1, {myId: 10, myString: 'foo'});

let v2 = factory(Klass1, {badVar: 10});
```

This matches your request, as the the 2nd call to `factory` results in an compilation error.

I changed the class members to be private/protected and instead of using `Object.assign` I use an `init` method to assign the values.
Why? because it's the object oriented thing to do.  This way you can use the hierarchy of the classes when assigning the values using `super.init` (or not calling it if you decide not to in a specific situation).
Basically you have more control this way.

[The code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20BaseProperties%20%7B%0A%09myId%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Base%3CT%20extends%20BaseProperties%3E%20%7B%0A%09protected%20myId%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%0A%20%20%20init(props%3A%20T)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20this.myId%20%3D%20props.myId%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Klass1Properties%20extends%20BaseProperties%20%7B%0A%09myString%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%09myNumber%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Klass1%20extends%20Base%3CKlass1Properties%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20private%20myString%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20private%20myNumber%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20init(props%3A%20Klass1Properties)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20super.init(props)%3B%0A%09%20%20%20%0A%09%20%20%20this.myString%20%3D%20props.myString%3B%0A%09%20%20%20this.myNumber%20%3D%20props.myNumber%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IBaseCtr%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20factory%3CP%20extends%20BaseProperties%2C%20T%20extends%20Base%3CP%3E%3E(ctrFunc%3A%20IBaseCtr%3CT%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20initialData%3F%3A%20P)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20new_obj%20%3D%20new%20ctrFunc()%3B%0A%20%20new_obj.init(initialData)%3B%0A%20%20%20return%20new_obj%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Alet%20v1%20%3D%20factory(Klass1%2C%20%7BmyId%3A%2010%2C%20myString%3A%20'foo'%7D)%3B%0A%0Alet%20v2%20%3D%20factory(Klass1%2C%20%7BbadVar%3A%2010%7D)%3B)

Comment: This is how I've often done it as well, but it doesn't work for a generic factory function which seems to be Allen's goal

Comment: @Paarth I added a link to the code in playground where it's clear that this is working well, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I suppose it depends on his intention. My interpretation of the problem was that the classes presented were purely for background and not necessarily the desired hierarchy. If I'm understanding your solution correctly, this will work for the hierarchy you've got defined but you'd have to set it up all over again for other classes.